“Worship” in Judaism?
I wanted to know if the term “worship” has any special significance in Judaism or not and why, for instance, in the Orthodox Jewish Bible the word for “bow down” is selectively translated as “worship” when it is applied to God / a god / an idol, but literally as “bow down” when applied towards men. For example:
Shemot 18:7
And Moshe went out to meet his khoten, bowed low (וַיִּשְׁתַּ֙חוּ֙), and kissed him; and they asked each other of their shalom (welfare); and they came into the ohel.
Compared with Shmuel Alef 15:31
So Shmuel turned back after Sha’ul; and Sha’ul worshiped (וַיִּשְׁתַּ֥חוּ) Hashem.
Is this purely a convention common in English translations of scripture, or is it understood that the act of bowing down when directed towards God is a fundamentally distinct action from bowing down towards men? And if the latter, why then does scripture use the same word for men to begin with? Is there perhaps a more reliable translation that you’d recommend than the OJB?

By the way, the "Orthodox Jewish Bible" is a dishonestly named Christian translation that has nothing to do with Orthodox Jews.

@Fred ah, that would make sense. I was curious about this translation practice precisely because I know Christian translations abuse this convention and was surprised that the “Jewish” translation followed suite. Thanks!

Check out the various translations at Sefaria.org. And the Hebrew (or Aramaic, actually) word for "work" or "serve" is the one actually also used for worship.

This question might need an expert in etymology to answer. Either way Shalom is right that that word means "bow", not worship, and עבד / פלח would be more commonly translated as "worship" in more authentic translations.
But maybe there is no specific translation of this english word into Lashon Hakodesh, in the same way that there is no english word for the german word "zeitgeist".
So, we should just look at how it is used in english. You'll note three predominant uses of the word in this google definition:

the feeling or expression of reverence and adoration for a deity.
religious rites or ceremonies, constituting a formal expression of reverence for a deity.
great admiration or devotion shown towards a person or principle.

Do we have any of those in Hebrew? Yes, all of the above is very true of Torah worship.

We feel love and fear of Hashem
We serve Hashem through Mitzvot (i.e. Avodah - service - including bowing when appropriate)
We also strive to have a personal admiration and devotion to Hashem

For 3, consider this. In english, when a man "worships" a woman, what does that mean? It means that he thinks she is absolutely perfect in every way. He can't see her flaws. As a result he admires her and is utterly devoted to her.
In Torah, Hashem is described as perfect. It's not just a theological technicality of Divine shelemut, but I heard my Rav say we should also understand it on this personal level too. We just think Hashem is absolutely perfect, flawless, and we wouldn't want anyone else. We absolutely worship Him!

Thank you :) Would translating the term as “service” be done when directed towards men? This seems like it could have similar theological implications as “worship” since there is a command to  serve God alone, but no command to “worship” / bow down to God alone. It is this sense of being something reserved for God alone that gets abused in orthodox Christian renderings of scripture

@RyanPierceWilliams a slave is an "eved" (servant), so yes, the word is used for human activities too, although we'd also advise caution about mixing words shared between the Divine relationship and inter-human relationships

But if the words are used by the scriptures themselves in common between men and God, then it seems erroneous to create distinctions only in translation? This practice is used in Christian translations to falsely bolster the Trinity by selectively translating the act of “bowing down” as “worship” when applied to Christ but literally as “bowing down” when applied to any other man.

@RyanPierceWilliams well, we have to be have some way to understand the bible. The issue with the Christians is not that the engage in exegesis but that they don't have an acceptable tradition or method for it. If a Christian says "yeah but you also engage in exegesis" I will say "this is a tradition from Sinai, I can show you, as well as prove it to you through exegtical rules. How did you get your drash?", they will at best say "well, Church tradition". And we reject that, especially due to the many mistranslations and the clear reverse-engineering "assumption first, proof later" approach

I agree with your general critique of Christian exegesis (speaking as a non-orthodox Christian), but I’m still not clear on why only in translation you would want to use distinct terms where the scriptures use the same terms with both men and God? This would be to create distinctions not present in the Hebrew

@RyanPierceWilliams I might have misunderstood your comment. I agree with the fact that selective translation is dodgy. It can in theory be done sometimes, but needs to be bolstered by the Oral Torah tradition which I mentioned in my previous comment. In this case, bowing is bowing. It should be translated the same for bowing to man and bowing to God. There might be other meanings of that exact hebrew root that might come into play in very different contexts, but this suffices for now

Thank you for clarifying :)

@RyanPierceWilliams and just to add, someone who is sincerely trying to translate the Torah according to Torah tradition might still translate the same word differently in different contexts, it's not always an indication of deception. Best approach is to find out what are the most well accepted translations in the orthodox world and stick to them, while working on your own hebrew on the side :)

Yes, words have a range of meaning that must be selected from. Though, in this case, I don’t think there’s either a Biblical Hebrew of Greek term that corresponds directly with the modern English concept of “worship.” There’s like 5 distinct terms that Christian translators will all convert to “worship” (selectively) rather than render the perfectly intelligible literal meaning.
